# Реализация if-then-else в Prelude

Tags: функции, haskell, функциональное-программирование

В книге Learn You a Haskell for Great Good, наткнулся на следующий пример реализации:

```
if' :: Bool –> a –> a –> a
if' True x _ = x
if' False _ y = y
```

Но в других источниках, узнал что if реализована на уровне ключевого слова.

Возник вопрос: Как на самом деле реализована функция if в стандартной библиотеке?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if` не в стандартной библиотеке. Это не функция, а часть синтаксиса языка.

`if`, в той форме, в которой оно присутствует в языке, нельзя реализовать как функцию, потому что нет механизма для реализации слов `then` и `else`.

Реализация `if'` в вашем примере эквивалентна по смыслу, но синтаксически выглядит не так. Сравните:

```
if f x y then g a else h b
if' (f x y) (g a) (h b)
```

На второй строке вагон лишних скобок и отсутствуют `then` и `else`. Строго говоря возможно, но программировать так гораздо неприятнее.

---

Дополнение, в ответ на комментарий от @bipll:

> Ч0ч0? В лиспе так и программируют.

В Лиспах скобки везде, это правда жизни, и от них никуда не деться. Форма `if` не исключение, она следует правилам синтаксиса.

В Хаскелле же (и вообще в ML) ситуация как раз противоположная: скобок стараются избежать насколько возможно. Отсюда и синтаксис `if`.

Но и в Лиспах, стоит заметить, форма `if` - это тоже не функция, а специальная форма, хотя и по другим причинам. Все известные мне Лиспы используют аппликативный порядок вычисления (т.е. агрументы функций вычисляются *до* передачи в функцию, а не после, как в Хаскелле). Поэтому если бы форма `if` была функцией, то при её вызове вычислялись бы и второй ("then") и третий ("else") аргументы, а не толко один из них. Это приводило бы не только к значительному падению скорости вычислений, но и к нежелательным побочным эффектам (в случае, когда одна или обе ветви содержат эффекты). Поэтому форма `if` не может быть функцией, она должна обрабатываться специальным образом.

Comment: Ч0ч0? В лиспе так и программируют.

Comment: @bipll я дополнил ответ

Comment: Ну да, там это тоже синтаксис, я сейчас не помню, базовая форма или ее все-таки возможно определить.

Comment: В модуле `Data.Bool` есть функция [`bool`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Bool.html#v:bool) - это `if'` из примера, но с перевернутыми аргументами. Конечно не стоит искать в ней полную замену `if`, но пользоваться ей порой очень даже приятно `bool "Even" "Odd" . odd . read <$> getLine`